# Test (selenium) Google Oauth login on my Django website

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, google-oauth

On our login screen we have a Google login.
But when I try to test it with Selenium I get an error at Google saying:
"device_id and device_name are required for private IP: http://..../accounts/google/login/callback/"

Error 400: invalid_request.

Now I have (I think) 2 options:

- Make it so the request is valid.
- Check the request we send to Google to see if it is valid Oauth and fake a response that back.

But I have no idea how to do them and which one is better then the other one.

The request we send to google has this payload:

```
"client_id": 
"redirect_uri": 
"scope": 
"response_type": 
"state": 
"access_type":
```

```
<!--begin::Google link-->
                <a href="{% provider_login_url "google" %}"
                   class="btn btn-flex flex-center btn-light btn-lg w-100 mb-5">
                    <img alt="Logo"
                         width="28" height="28"
                         src="{% manifest "media/svg/brand-logos/google-icon.svg" %}"
                         class="h-20px me-3" />
                    {% trans "Continue with Google" %}
                </a>
                <!--end::Google link-->
```

When I tried clicking in the Selenium browser on the google I Expected for it to show the normal google login.

Instead of the normal google login I got an error.